# Combining feature extraction classes in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm using `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` to chain feature extractors and a classifier. Is there a way to combine multiple feature selection classes (for example the ones from `sklearn.feature_selection.text`) in parallel and join their output?

My code right now looks as follows:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier())])
```

It results in the following:

```
vect -> tfidf -> clf
```

I want to be able to specify a pipeline that looks as follows:

```
vect1 -> tfidf1 \
                 -> clf
vect2 -> tfidf2 /
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been implemented recently in the master branch of scikit-learn under the name `FeatureUnion`:

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/pipeline.html#feature-union

Comment: Yup, I saw it at http://blog.kaggle.com/2012/09/26/impermium-andreas-blog/ after I asked the question

Comment: Cool, a first user :) Let me know if you find it useful!