# Combining multiple parameters for creating SVM vector

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

New to scikit-learn and I am working with some data like the following.

```
data[0] = {"string": "some arbitrary text", "label1": "orange", "value1" : False }
data[0] = {"string": "some other arbitrary text", "label1": "red", "value1" : True }
```

For single lines of text there is `CountVectorizer` and `DictVectorizer` in the pipeline before `TfidfTransformer`. The output of these could be concatenated, I'm hoping with the following caveat:  The arbitrary text I don't want to be equal in importance to the specific, limited and well-defined parameters.

Finally, some other questions, possibly related

- might this data structure indicate which SVM kernel is best?
- Or would a Random Forest/Decision Tree, DBN, or Bayes classifier possibly do better in this case? Or an [Ensemble method](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/ensemble.html)? (The output is [multi-class](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/multiclass.html))
- I see there is an upcoming feature for [feature union](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/pipeline.html#feature-union), but this is to run different methods over the same data and combine them.
- Should I be using [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_selection.html)?

See also:

- [Implementing Bag-of-Words Naive-Bayes classifier in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098533/implementing-bag-of-words-naive-bayes-classifier-in-nltk)
- [Combining feature extraction classes in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721486/combining-feature-extraction-classes-in-scikit-learn)
- http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/label_propagation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classifiers in scikit-learn(*) expect a flat feature representation for samples, so you'll probably want to turn your `string` feature into a vector. First, let get some incorrect assumptions out of the way:

- `DictVectorizer` is not for handling "lines of text", but for arbitrary symbolic features.
- `CountVectorizer` is also not for handling lines, but for entire text documents.
- Whether features are "equal in importance" is mostly up to the learning algorithm, though with a kernelized SVM, you can assign artificially small weights to features to make its dot products come out differently. I'm not saying that's a good idea, though.

There are two ways of handling this kind of data:

1. Build a `FeatureUnion` consisting of a `CountVectorizer` (or `TfidfVectorizer`) for your textual data and a `DictVectorizer` for the additional features.
2. Manually split the textual data into words, then use each word as a feature in a `DictVectorizer`, e.g.

   ```
   {"string:some": True, "string:arbitrary": True, "string:text": True,
    "label1": "orange", "value1" : False }
   ```

Then the related questions:

- might this data structure indicate which SVM kernel is best?

Since you're handling textual data, try a `LinearSVC` first and a polynomial kernel of degree 2 if it doesn't work. RBF kernels are a bad match for textual data, and cubic or higher-order poly kernels tend to overfit badly. As an alternative to kernels, you can manually construct products of individual features and train a `LinearSVC` on that; sometimes, that works better than a kernel. It also gets rid of the feature importances issue as a `LinearSVC` learns per-feature weights.

- Or would a Random Forest/Decision Tree, DBN, or Bayes classifier possibly do better in this case?

That's impossible to tell without trying. scikit-learn's random forests and dtrees unfortunately don't handle sparse matrices, so they're rather hard to apply. DBNs are not implemented.

- Should I be using feature selection?

Impossible to tell without seeing the data.

(*) Except SVMs if you implement custom kernels, which is such an advanced topic that I won't discuss it now.

Comment: Thanks for answering a mix of specific and general questions thoroughly. LinearSVC can have class weights [1]. Why do you recommend against? Or is it that you aren't recommending because it's a data specific question?  

[1] - http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC

Comment: I'm not recommending against `LinearSVC`, I'm all for it for handling textual data. And class weights have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I was trying to clarify that you were against using weights. " ... though with a kernelized SVM, you can assign artificially small weights to features to make its dot products come out differently. I'm not saying that's a good idea, though." Thanks again.

Comment: *Feature* weights, not class weights. Clarifying this comment: I personally have better experience with generating products of features manually (followed by feature selection) than using polynomial kernels and `SVC`.